# Finding the kernel of a group endomorphism of a multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was hoping that you guys could give me some tips about how to think about this algebra problem.

Fix a field $k$ and let $k^*$ be the multiplicative group of it's non-zero elements, and let $\phi:k^*\to{k^*}$ with
$\phi(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in{k^*}$.

The first thing it was to show that it is a group homomorphism and I had no troubles with that.

however when it was asked to show that the $|ker(\phi)|$ if $char(k)= 2$ and if $char(k)\neq 2$ then it had two elements I have no idea on how to proceed.

if the $ker(\phi)=\{x|x^2=1\}$ and it has characteristic 2, wouldn't that imply that $1^2=0$, and therefore $1\notin{k^*}$?

I hope I have made myself clear and thank you all guys very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have $x^2=1\iff x=1\vee x=-1$. So, if $\operatorname{char}(k)\ne2$, then $-1\ne1$, and therefore $|\ker\phi|=2$. But, if $\operatorname{char}(k)=2$, then $-1=1$, and then $|\ker\phi|=1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! one question, would $-1$ be the number or just the inverse of the identity, because wouldn't that be just the same element in $k^*$?

Comment: In all that I am doing, I am working in $k$. In particular, both $1$ and $-1$ are elements of $k$. And they are equal if an only if $\operatorname{char}(k)=2$, since$$1=-1\iff1+1=0\iff\operatorname{char}(k)=2.$$